# How to fix an External 4TB HDD with HFSPlus Filesystem stuck on Read-Only

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, read-only

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 with a 4TB External HDD attached with a HFSPlus Filesystem, non-journaled.  At some point the HDD would become read-only despite all efforts to mount it at another location besides "/media", change permissions, or amend FSTAB.  I used instructions found elsewhere on this very helpful askUbuntu forum.

Finally, I came across some instructions to run DMESG to see the output.

> hfsplus: Filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  mounting read-only.

After further reading I believe the HDD was improperly mounted and this is a textbook case of not properly and safely disconnecting the drive from Ubuntu.  I understand that the solution is to run "fsck.hfsplus".  However, I quickly learned that I don't have that command available.  I tried to install it with apt-get, but there's no package by that name.

I am missing something, but I just need to know how to repair the situation.

I am someone who has been tinkering with Linux on a superficial level since University with a background in Arts.  I set up Piholes and I use Ubuntu mainly to entertain family as a media centre.  Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: After some further reading, though initially not very clear, I installed HFSProgs which happened to include the fsck.hfsplus command that I was looking for.  Now since I have the External drive mounted automatically at "/disks/media1" I ran fsck.hfsplus on that location.  I got this output in return: 'code' ** /disks/media1/ (NO WRITE)
Device is not a block device

Comment: Out of frustration, I resorted to unmounting the HDD from my Linux unit directly into an Apple laptop.  I noted that the HDD connected without issue.  I ran First Aid on the drive, which ran and completed without any noted issues.  I then reconnected the drive to Ubuntu and the drive has returned to normal.  I would have preferred finding a Ubuntu solution, but practicalities led me to this route instead.